# Re: Hangman Using Modules, How to draw out the Hangman using plain css, html, and javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on a simple hangman application and I have all of the functionality worked out for the most part, the thing I am having a little trouble with is actually drawing out the hangman on wrong guesses.  I have separated all the components into modules and have listed them below. I would appreciate it if I could get some ideas or examples on how to get my incorrect responses to activate the respective divs for drawing out the gallows and hanging man.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/styles/hangman.css">
     <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">
     <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-b5kHyXgcpbZJO/tY9Ul7kGkf1S0CWuKcCD38l8YkeH8z8QjE0GmW1gYU5S9FOnJ0" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
     <title>JavaScript | Hangman</title>
</head>
<body>
     <header class="header col-lg-12">
          <h1>JavaScript Hangman Game</h1>
        </header>
        <div id="gallows col-lg-4">
          <div class="right-bar"></div>
          <div class="top-bar"></div>
          <div class="left-bar"></div>
          <div class="base"></div>
    
          <div class="head"></div>
          <div class="body"></div>
          <div class="left-arm"></div>
          <div class="right-arm"></div>
          <div class="left-leg"></div>
          <div class="right-leg"></div>
    
          <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>

        <div id="hangman col-log-8">
          <div id="display-status"></div>
          <div id="letter-slots"></div>
          <div id="keyboard"></div>
          <button id="restart">Restart</button>
        </div>
     
     <script src="dist/build.js" defer></script>
</body>
</html>
```

entry point -> hangman.js

```
import "regenerator-runtime/runtime";
//Bring in the modules being used
import getRandomWord from './words_list';
import { isStillPlaying } from './game_status';
import letterSlots from './letter_slots';
import keyboard from './keyboard_layout';
import displayStatus from './game_display_status';
import restartGame from './new_game';


//Start and play
function drawGame(word, letters) {
     document.querySelector('#display-status').innerHTML = displayStatus(word, letters);
     document.querySelector('#letter-slots').innerHTML = letterSlots(word, letters);
     document.querySelector('#keyboard').innerHTML = keyboard(letters);
}

getRandomWord(word => {
     const letters = [];

     document.addEventListener('click', event => {
          if(isStillPlaying(word, letters) && event.target.tagName === 'BUTTON') {
               letters.push(event.target.dataset.character);
               drawGame(word, letters);
          }
     });
     drawGame(word, letters);
     restartGame();
});
```

words_list.js

```
import newHttpRequest from './send_http_request';

//Use fetch API via Send Http Request

async function getWords(cb) {
     try {
     cb(await newHttpRequest(
       'GET', 
       'https://random-word-api.herokuapp.com/word?number=50'
       ));
     } catch(error) {
       alert(error.message);
     }
   }

//Select a random word

export default async function getRandomWord(cb) {
     try {
      await getWords(words => {
        const randomWord = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];
        cb(randomWord.toUpperCase());
      });
     } catch(error) {
       alert(error);
     }
    }
```

send_http_request.js

```
//Create an http request
export default function newHttpRequest(method, url, data) {
     return fetch(url, {
          method: method,
          body: data
     }).then(response => {
          if(response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
               return response.json();
          } else {
               return response.json().then(errorData => {
                    console.log(errorData);
                    throw new Error('Something went wrong server-side! Please try again later.')
               })
          }
     }).catch(error => {
          console.log(error);
          throw new Error('Something went wrong! Please try again later.')
     })
}
```

new_game.js

```
function newGame() {
     document.location.reload(window);
}

export default function restartGame() {
     const restart = document.getElementById('restart');
     restart.addEventListener('click', newGame);
}
```

letter_slots.js

```
//Create spans that are empty or contain a letter
function letterSlot(letter, letters) {
     if(letters.includes(letter)) {
          return `<span>${letter}</span>`
     } else {
          return `<span>&nbsp;</span>`
     }
}
//Export the function to use 
export default function letterSlots(word, letters) {
     
     const slots = word.split('').map(letter => letterSlot(letter, letters));

     return `<div>${ slots.join('') }</div>`
}
```

keyboard_layout.js

```
//Store the letters
const alphabet = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'.split("");

//Divide the letters into three rows
const row1 = alphabet.slice(0, 10);
const row2 = alphabet.slice(10, 19);
const row3 = alphabet.slice(19, 26);

//Show or hide buttons
function key(letter, letters) {
     if(letters.includes(letter)) {
          return `<span>${letter}</span>`
     } else {
          return `<button data-character=${letter}>${letter}</button>`
          
     }
}
//Export keyboard and map letters to buttons
export default function keyboard(letters) {
     return `
     <div>${ row1.map(character => key(character, letters)).join('') }</div>
     <div>${ row2.map(character => key(character, letters)).join('') }</div>
     <div>${ row3.map(character => key(character, letters)).join('') } </div>
     `
}
```

game_status.js

```
//Set wrong guesses
const MAX_WRONG_LETTERS = 15;

//Find all the letters
export function lettersRemaining(word, letters) {
     const wrongLetters = letters.filter((character) => !word.includes(character));
     return MAX_WRONG_LETTERS - wrongLetters.length;
}

//Are the letters guessed
export function isGameWon(word, letters) {
     return !word.split("").find(letter => !letters.includes(letter));
}

//If no letters and game not won, game over
export function isGameOver(word, letters) {
     return !lettersRemaining(word, letters) && !isGameWon(word, letters);
}

//Still in play
export function isStillPlaying(word, letters) {
     return (
          lettersRemaining(word, letters) &&
          !isGameOver(word, letters) && 
          !isGameWon(word, letters)
     );
}
```

game_display_status.js

```
import * as status from './game_status';

//invoke imported functions
function getMessage(word, letters) {
     if(status.isGameWon(word, letters)) {
          return "You Win!"
     } else if(status.isGameOver(word, letters)) {
          return 'Game Over!'
     } else {
          return `Chances remaining: ${status.lettersRemaining(word, letters)}`
     }
}

//Export what to display
export default function displayStatus(word, letters) {
     return `<div> ${getMessage(word, letters)}</div>`
}
```

hangman.css

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  background: gainsboro;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.header {
  padding: 1px;
  text-align: center;
  background: slateblue;
  color: white;
}

#hangman {
  margin: 100px 0;
  text-align: center;
}

#hangman > div {
  margin: 50px;
}

#display-status {
  color: black;
  font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 30px;
}

#letter-slots span {
  color: black;
  border-bottom: 3px solid black;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 24px;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 2em;
  display: inline-block;
}

#keyboard button,
#keyboard span {
  background: darkslateblue;
  color: gainsboro;
  border: 3px outset darkslategrey;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 18px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 2.5em;
}

#keyboard span {
  opacity: 0.3;
}
.logo {
  color: black;
}
#restart {
  color: gainsboro;
  background-color: darkslateblue;
  border: 3px outset darkslategrey;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.name {
  color: blue;
}

.page-footer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background-color: slateblue;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
p {
  font-size: 19px;
  font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: black;
}
#gallows {
     height: 405px;
     margin: 0 auto;
     width: 300px;
   }
   
   #gallows div {
     background: #FFF;
   }
   
   #gallows .base {
     height: 2px;
     width: 300px;
   }
   
   #gallows .left-bar {
     height: 400px;
     width: 2px;
   }
   
   #gallows .top-bar {
     height: 2px;
     width: 200px;
   }
   
   #gallows .right-bar {
     float: left;
     height: 30px;
     margin-left: 200px;
     width: 2px;
   }
   
   #gallows .head {
     background: none;
     border-radius: 100%;
     float: left;
     margin-left: 175px;
     margin-top: -375px;
     height: 50px;
     width: 50px;
   }
   
   #gallows .body {
     float: left;
     height: 140px;
     margin-top: -321px;
     margin-left: 200px;
     width: 2px;
   }
   
   #gallows .left-arm,
   #gallows .right-arm,
   #gallows .left-leg,
   #gallows .right-leg {
     float: left;
     height: 90px;
     margin-top: -321px;
     margin-left: 173px;
     transform: rotate(35deg);
     width: 2px;
   }
   
   #gallows .right-arm,
   #gallows .right-leg {
     margin-left: 230px;
     margin-top: -324px;
     transform: rotate(140deg);
   }
   
   #gallows .left-leg,
   #gallows .right-leg {
     margin-top: -192px;
   }
   
   #gallows.lifes-10 .base {
     background: #000;
   }
   
   #gallows.lifes-9 .left-bar {
     background: #000;
   }
   
   #gallows.lifes-8 .top-bar {
     background: #000;
   }
   
   #gallows.lifes-7 .right-bar {
     background: #000;
   }
   
   #gallows.lifes-6 .head {
     border: 2px solid #000;
   }
   
   #gallows.lifes-5 .body {
     background: #000;
   }
   
   #gallows.lifes-4 .left-arm {
     background: #000;
   }
   
   #gallows.lifes-3 .right-arm {
     background: #000;
   }
   
   #gallows.lifes-2 .left-leg {
     background: #000;
   }
   
   #gallows.lifes-1 .right-leg {
     background: #000;
   }
```

Thank you all in advance.  I am learning albeit at a very slow pace.

Comment: I would suggest to either use canvas or maybe you just store multiple pictures of each stage of hangman, and change the src of the images based on the stage. I guess that would be the easiest way to solve this (if you want to work only with plain js/html/css)

Comment: You seem to have all the body parts and gallows already. If you set them all to display none and then display block when you want to show the part is that enough? Can you point out where in your code exactly you find you want to show the next part (ie an erroneous guess)?

Comment: I was thinking it should go in the hangman.js file in the getRandomWord function after the click event that manipulates the display on the keyboard. Maybe make a draw_hangman.js module with a function that I can call or add into the click event somehow like the drawGame and restartGame funtions? I know what I want to do, I am just having a hard time with the where and how. A Haworth.